# What happens to the free space of HDD2 if dd is used to write the smaller device HDD1, to HDD2?

Tags: linux, bash, data-recovery, dd, forensics

What happens to the space left on `sdb` in this case? I assume `dd` will write the data at the beginning, replace the partition table, and the free space will be untouched (not usable).

`sda` = 10 GB
`sdb` = 15 GB

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

I know the free space is not useable and someone would have to partition to the correct size before running dd. I do not care about the free space in this case. I'm looking for a technical answer to my question. Like on a data forensic level.

Comment: For basic obvious resource savings, I guess all remaining space is untouched. That would also means that a forensic analysis could read those "abandonned" data. IMO.

Comment: "What happens?" – Nothing. `dd` stops when it gets to the end of `sda` and some trailing part of `sdb` is not altered. You seem to know this, as you used the word "untouched" (= "not altered", right?). Or I'm misinterpreting. What do you mean by "free space"? This term is usually used in the context of filesystems. In the context of block devices that may be partitioned there may be "unallocated space".

Answer (score 0):

Your command will take the entire contents of `/dev/sda` and (slowly) write it to the first part of `/dev/sdb`. The remainder of `/dev/sdb` will be untouched.

In practical terms, using the `dd` command as you've written it will be bounded by the repeated syscalls for each 512 byte read/write. You will get significantly better performance by increasing the buffer size or even just using `cat`. There will be no difference to the copy:

```
cat /dev/sda >/dev/sdb
```

You can test these behaviours by creating much smaller loopback devices

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 >/tmp/100M.img
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=150 >/tmp/150M.img

lda=$(losetup --find --show); echo device $lda
ldb=$(losetup --find --show); echo device $ldb

# Try your commands here
dd if=$lda of=$ldb
```

You can now see how much of `$ldb` was overwritten by `$lda`